# Show that the set $\{\frac{1}{n}|n\in\mathbb{Z^{+}}\} \cup \{0\}$ is compact

Tags: general-topology

> A collection of open disks  in $\mathbb {R x R}$ is called a cover for
>   a set $S$ if each element of $S$ is in one of the disks. Let
>   $S=\{\frac{1}{n}|n\in\mathbb{Z^{+}}\} \cup \{0\}$ and let $C$ be any open cover for $S$.
>   Prove that there exist sets $X_{i}$ $(i=1,2,3...,n)$ where
>   $\cup^n_{i=1}X_{i}$ is an open cover for $S$ and $X_{i}\in S$ for all
>   $i$.
>
> Fun fact: A set $S$ is called compact if any open cover for $S$ has a finite subcover. Hence, you are being asked here to show that $\{\frac{1}{n}|n\in\mathbb{Z}\} \cup \{0\}$ is compact.

I don't understand where to even start proving this. I've been given the hint that, given C, is it possible to find a set $A$ such that $\forall x\in S, \exists c\in A$ such that $x\in c$, where $A \subset C$ and $|A|<\infty$, but I don't really understand what to do with that.

Comment: Do you know the Heine-Borel theorem? This reduces it to problem that you need to show your set is closed.

Also, I'm not sure I'd call the definition of compactness "fun", per se.

Comment: Check that you're giving a definition of 'cover' in $\mathbb{R}^2$ but your set $S$ is a subset of $\mathbb{R}$. Anyway, the definition is right if you change 'open disks' to 'open sets'.

Comment: @AlejandroNasifSalum It's not the right definition in general, but here at least, it's equivalent with the regular one, since open discs form a basis for $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: Sure. What I was trying to avoid is the specificity of the word 'disk' for a two dimensional space, 'interval' for one dimension, 'sphere' for 3D and so on.

Answer (score 4):

A neighborhood of $0$ contains an infinite numbers of elements.

Let $U_i$ be an open cover of $S$, suppose that $0\in U_{i_0}$, $U_{i_0}=U\cap S$ where $U$ is an open subset of $\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}$, this implies that there exists $r>0$ such that $B(0,r)\subset U$ for every $n$ such that $1/n<r, 1/n\in U$ so $1/n\in U_{i_0}$. Let $N$ such that $1/N<r$, for $n< N$, $i/n\in U_{i_n}$ so you can extract the finite cover $U_{i_0},U_{i_1},...,U_{i_N}$.